# Suppose that $f\colon [0, \infty)\to \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f\colon [0, \infty)\to \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}  \sup\{ f'(t) \colon t>x\} = 1$.
Prove that for every $k>1$, there exists $b\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\le k x+b$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$.

For some large enough $x^*$, it is easy to use MVT. My confuse is on the interval $[0,x^*]$. But now I know how to prove it on $[0,x^*]$ by using extreme value theorem.

Comment: Can you show your effort ? MVT gives the answer immediately.

Comment: my idea is that first we can find $x^*$ which is large enough that for any $x\ge x^*$, $f'(x)\le 1$. So let $g(x)=f(x)-kx$ $g(x)$ is decreasing on $[x^*,\infty]$. And on $[0,x^*]$ part use MVT to show that there exists $t\in [0,x^*]$ such that $f'(t)=0$. Then we can let $b=max(f(t),f(x^*))$. But I am not very sure.

Comment: @xyz: Please include the explanation in your answer for future references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $k>1$ the there exist $x^{*}$ such that $f(x) <k$ for all $x \geq x^{*}$. Hence, $x \geq x^{*}$ implies $f(x)-f(x^{*})=f'(t) (x-x^{*}) <k(x-x^{*})$ for some $t$ between $x$ and $x^{*}$. Take $c=f(x^{*})-kx^{*}$. The we get $f(x)\leq kx+c$ for $x \geq x^{*}$. Now $f$ is bounded on $[0,x^{*}]$ so there exist $M$ such that $f(x) \leq M$ for $x \in  [0,x^{*}]$. Take $b=\max \{c,M\}$ to finish the proof.